# Session id to be passed in api request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am doing Api testing using jmeter.

I have session_id extracted from HTTP Request1 ${sessionId_g1} response using REGEX and passing to HTTP Request 2 request ${sessionId_g1}.but i am getting below error:

"Failure while checking user access. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to verify SSO values with token info; token decryption has failed."

Please let me know which one i missed here?

Comment: Sorry. i posted wrongly initially .change the question

Comment: Anybody can help on this?

Comment: you probably missing token, you should check what you missing for getting successful request

Comment: I didn't find any token in my request and while doing same above manually in soap ui,it is working fine.i didn't pass token explicitly except session id in 2nd request